# How to concatinate customize School Year in C#

Tags: c#, date, primary-key

Can someone help me please? 
I have a program where I can add multiple entries of School Year. The primary ID format should be i.e. SY17-18, SY18-19, and so on. I did get the format but I am using DateTime.Now to get the current year hence the primary ID would stay the same everytime I run the program since I am basing it on the DateTime. 
Here is my code:

```
int curr = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy"));
int dt = curr + 1;
string sy = "SY" + curr + "-" + dt;
txtSYID.Text = sy;
```

How can I able to produce this kind of format where it automatically concatenate without having to based in the current year.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "without having to based in the current year"? You can use any year you want, but where will you get it from?

Comment: I doubt your logic for determining the formatted school year is valid, by the way. You don't go from school year 17-18 to 19-20, but to 18-19. A given year is always in _two_ school years: 2018 is in SY17-18 and in SY18-19, depending on the time in that year.

Comment: I am sorry but that should be in order SY. I was wrong with jumping off right away to 19-20. Since my program is based on the DateTime.Now, I was trying to find a way how to concatenate the SY in order when I would enter many SY entries.

Comment: How many previous or future years do you need that you need to check or atleast you need a a start year to start with

Comment: @Lauren was my answer what you meant, or I have got it wrong?

Comment: Hi Arijit, atleast to start at year 2017.

Comment: atleast I start with SY17-18 then SY18-19 and going forward.

Comment: @Lauren you are just looking for a function to create these: SY17-18, SY18-19, ...?

Comment: Yes, that's it. A function that would automatically concatenate the SY - @AshkanMobayenKhiabani.

Answer (score 1):

If Current DateTime shows 2018/10 then we are in `SY18-19` however 2019/3 is still `SY18-19` ( I have set the 6th month as the end of the school year however you can change it it was only to set an example):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
int curr = date.Year;
if(date.Month <= 6) curr--;  
string sy = $"SY{curr}-{curr + 1}";
```

**Edit** (considering your comment): 
If you want to generate school years only you can do this (you dont need datetime):

```
Enumerable.Range(17, 50).Select(x=> $"SY{x}-{x+1}").ToArray();
```

the above code will give you an array containing school year up to SY50-51.

if you want it in a comma separated string:

```
for(int i=17;i<50;i++)
   sy += $",SY{i}-{i+1}";

sy = sy.SubString(1);
```

Comment: Its for the Enum Range solution

Comment: well i wrote what I understood, OP should say if it is what she wants

Comment: Hi @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, Thank you for your input. May I ask, what's the '$' for? It's error in my end. It says ' ; Expected ' .

Comment: $ is for formatting text, if you are using an older version of C#, instead of for example `$",SY{i}-{i+1}"` you can either use `string.Format(",SY{0}-{1}", i, i+1)` or `",SY" + i.ToString() + "-" + (i+1).ToString()`

Comment: you are welcome. dont forget to mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: well what i meant was plus one for the enum range solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ToFinancialYearShort(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return "SY: " + (dateTime.Month >= 4 ? (dateTime.ToString("yy") 
+ " - " +dateTime.AddYears(1).ToString("yy")) : (dateTime.AddYears(-1).ToString("yy") + " - " + dateTime.ToString("yy")));
}
```

This Should work

Comment: Thank you for your help Arijit. I was just wondering how can I display the return value in the textbox because it should be loaded when the form loads. Sorry for bothering so much.

Comment: Hi Arijit, it should be in the textbox whenever I run the program it should generate the primary key right away before I enter a new school year

Comment: What you can do is simply assign the value of the function to the textboc value